# how do I override appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, dom, overriding

```
appendChild = function(message) {
    console.log("intercepted!");
}
```

using the code above does not seem to work.

Anyone knows?

Comment: +1 Great question; I learned something new.

Comment: because I am writing about master thesis about bookmarklet, now I need to describe its weaknesses and how rouges can exploit it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you might want to replace is `Element.prototype.appendChild` but it's probably a bad idea.

This example adds the text `intercepted` in the inserted element :

```
var f = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild = function(){f.apply(this, arguments);arguments[0].innerHTML="!Intercepted!"; };
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/575qs/)

Comment: Be careful, the appendChild function is supposed to return the newly appended node. I suggest inverting the code inside your function and returning the f.apply() response.

Answer (score 4):

It is ill advised to overwrite native functions, but if you do it than make sure you return the appended element as well to prevent problems with code that uses the returned value of the native "appendChild" function:

```
window.callbackFunc = function(elem, args) {
  // write some logic here
}
window.f = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild = function() {
    window.callbackFunc.call(this, arguments);
    return window.f.apply(this, arguments);
};
```