# Handle the events of the beginning and end of an ajax request sent by a third-party library

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a third-party library in my project which sends some ajax requests. It's a quite complex library and it sends them to the urls which have a random GUID so I can't predict what the GUIDs would be and thus what the exact url would be.

I want to be able to handle the beginning and end of the ajax requests it sends so I can show an ajax spinner or something - to inform the user that there's something going on. Especially when the page is getting loaded for the first time.

I tried this for the even when it's already done but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
  alert('done');
});
```

And    `document.ready` didn't work the way I needed either because the responses from the ajax request came back after it.

Again, I'm not sending those ajax request, the library sends them. **For the sake of simplicity we can assume there's only one ajax request, not many.** And I can't change the source code of the library.

Is there any way?

**UPDATE:**

Isn't not using jquery. And it creates a script dynamically by

```
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = url;
    s.async = true;
    s.onreadystatechange = s.onload = function(){
     //.... some stuff
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @DGS, a library which isn't available in the Internet.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp  if it calling ajax then check this jquery function http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the global ajax event handlers only work when the event was made with jQuery. If the library does not make use of jQuery it will probably not register the events

Comment: There are [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) that might suit your needs. There are no native global events to hook for all XHR requests. You could try shimming the prototype, but that might not work on some browsers, depends on how they implement native objects. I'm looking at you, IE. If you do try to shim the prototype, you'll have to do that first thing on the document, before the offending library is added to the page.

Comment: If your goal is to simply **stop** the first ajax request, you could break the prototype on purpose, include the script, then fix the prototype. Might work.

Comment: @ChrisBaker, how? Look my update please.

Comment: It depends on how the script makes the request. If it is only using the XMLHttpRequest (no attempt to use the IE ActiveXObject method), then you can store `XMLHttpRequest` as something else, set `XMLHttpRequest` to a dummy object that acts like the real thing but does nothing, include the library, then restore XMLHttpRequest. Just an idea, you'd have to try it to see. If it makes the request using JSONP (creating a script tag, then parsing the response), you'll have to think of something else.

Comment: Is this library doing a jsonp callback? Then in that case...explain the last line...what it does...(referring to code as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29465821/5) update)...Specifically mention if the library has an api/method that initiates the request and a callback to handle it...

Answer (score 1):

There are no native global events related to AJAX requests. This is *partially* because there is not a complete cross-browser standard for implementation. Most browsers use `XMLHttpRequest`, IE uses `ActiveXObject`.

As noted in comments, jQuery implements [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), specifically `ajaxStart()` and `ajaxStop()`. These give you a place to hook in to all ajax events, and since jQuery provides a unified API for these you don't have to worry about the differences in implementation between browsers.

The jQuery events only help with requests that also use jQuery. For requests initiated without using the library, before OR after the library is included, these events won't be fired by jQuery because jQuery simply has no idea the requests occurred -- no global events for you, no global events for jQuery.

That leaves you with one last, somewhat drastic option -- interfere with the prototype. Depending on what you need to do, this could be accomplished in two ways. To simply **stop all requests**, you can replace the objects other code will rely on with nothing. The scripts that try to make an AJAX request will simply fail. You can later restore the objects. Here's a non-cross-browser mock-up:

```
<head>
    <script>
        var oldXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
        XMLHttpRequest = false; // now all ajax requests fail
    </script>

    <!-- include the problematic library here -->

    <script>
        XMLHttpRequest = oldXMLHttpRequest; // now they work again!
        oldXMLHttpRequest = null;
    </script>
```

Here is a proof-of-concept (not tested for IE, but should work): http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/wk0f7oeq/

If the goal is not to stop the request, but to take some action beforehand, you could write an object that behaves like XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject, but lets you hook in to the request. Replace `XMLHttpRequest` (or the IE counterpart) with your shimmed object, then optionally restore the original when your work is done. This is a little more involved, but not too tough. Instead of making `XMLHttpRequest` be false, make it be your functional replacement object.

Some browsers might not like you tampering with native objects, though, so be sure to test either approach on all target platforms.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a jsonp callback.

The JSONP works in a fashion similar to how you written code in the post [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29465821/5). But for a more formal understanding see [this](http://schier.co/blog/2013/09/30/how-jsonp-works.html).

Assuming that your library isn't written in a way to allow you to invoke some routines (functions) at critical stages like before the jsonp request, and, after jsonp request completes...you can override the `appendChild` routine as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14265251/145682).

Your focus is to extend the functionality of `appendChild`. Intercept the insertion of a `script` element; attach the handlers to it. And you are done...I hope...

Of course, this is a bad idea to put it to production.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ijElm8bQ5u895TMsYJ6D?p=preview

```
var f = Element.prototype.appendChild;
var precb = function() {
  console.log('precb called');
};

var postcb = function() {
  console.log('postcb called');
};

Element.prototype.appendChild = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  var el = args[0];

  if(el.tagName && el.tagName.toString().toLowerCase() === 'script') {
    precb();
    el.addEventListener('load', postcb, false);
  }
  f.apply(this, args);
};
```

Comment: 1) What does it have to do with jsonp? 2) And why do assume that this `el.addEventListener('load', , postcb, false);` will be executed right after we receive the ajax response from the servers? 3) How is it applicable to my case - where should I insert all this?

Comment: jsonp - thats the pattern of code I could make out from your SO post...have you gone through the example plunk i've posted...?